# Get subset of a matrix based on a vector

Tags: r, matrix

Let say I have below matrix

```
Mat = matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:5], letters[1:5]))
```

Now I want to subset this matrix based on below `vector` as column

```
Vec = c("a", "c", "x", "b", "y")

Mat[, Vec]
```

With this I get below error -

```
Error in Mat[, Vec] : subscript out of bounds
```

I know this error is by `R`'s design. However I want to make it work, such that the elements corresponding to unknown column names would come as `NA`

Is there any way to achieve this in `R`?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `match` ?

```
Mat = matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:5], letters[1:5]))      
                                                                                
Vec = c("a", "c", "x", "b", "y")                                                

Mat[, match(Vec, colnames(Mat))]
```

Which outputs

> ```
> > Mat[, match(Vec, colnames(Mat))]                                                                                                         
>             a          c <NA>          b <NA>                                                                                               
>  A  0.2427570 -0.4060827   NA  0.4698090   NA                                                                                               
>  B  1.5994373 -0.5916460   NA -0.4074645   NA                                                                                               
>  C  0.2120962 -1.4829029   NA -1.0006933   NA                                                                                               
>  D -0.6991751  0.6605346   NA -0.6403174   NA                                                                                               
>  E -0.2155225  0.8447741   NA -0.8743710   NA
> ```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `intersect` to take into account of the column names that are not present in the `matrix` but only in the `vector`

```
mat2 <- Mat[, intersect(Vec, colnames(Mat))]
```

-output

```
mat2
      a          c           b
A  0.28358265  0.4285490 -0.64482025
B  0.04228662 -0.7667130 -0.19550185
C -0.57197755 -1.8296791 -0.76012324
D -0.72591283  0.2336603  0.45026240
E -1.13775762 -1.9874356 -0.02215211
```

If we need to create new columns

```
nm1 <- setdiff(Vec, colnames(Mat))
nm2 <- setNames(rep(NA, length(nm1)), nm1)
cbind(mat2, t(nm2)[rep(1, nrow(mat2)),])
```

---

An easier option would be

```
Vec <- letters[1:3]
mat2 <- matrix(NA, nrow(Mat), length(Vec),
    dimnames = list(row.names(Mat), Vec))
v1 <- intersect(colnames(Mat), Vec)
mat2[,v1]  <- Mat[, v1]


mat2
#           a          b           c
#A -0.3811391 -0.7600103 -1.33100900
#B  0.4015464  1.2833597  1.06669817
#C  0.1582268  0.1562223  0.61765738
#D  1.5972361  1.4957370  0.45159383
#E  0.1970359 -0.8246555  0.03037087
```

Or with the original `Vec`

```
Vec = c("a", "c", "x", "b", "y")
mat2 <- matrix(NA, nrow(Mat), length(Vec),
     dimnames = list(row.names(Mat), Vec))
v1 <- intersect(colnames(Mat), Vec)
 mat2[,v1]  <- Mat[, v1]
 mat2
#           a           c  x          b  y
#A -0.3811391 -1.33100900 NA -0.7600103 NA
#B  0.4015464  1.06669817 NA  1.2833597 NA
#C  0.1582268  0.61765738 NA  0.1562223 NA
#D  1.5972361  0.45159383 NA  1.4957370 NA
#E  0.1970359  0.03037087 NA -0.8246555 NA
```

Comment: thanks! however I hope there is some easier method available. I need to apply this approach for both columns and rows

Comment: @BrianSmith you can check the updated method

Comment: Thanks again! But this approach gives an error if `Vec = letters[1:3]`

Comment: @BrianSmith it is just that earlier the length(Vec) was same a s `nrow(Mat)`.  I updated

Comment: @BrianSmith Please note that I didn't update the `row` part here as the `Mat` rownames are completely different when compared to Vec

Comment: Still does not appear complete. for `Vec = letters[1:3]` case, it is now reporting full matrix, not just `3` column matrix

Comment: @BrianSmith May be I understand your question differently.  I thought you want the `union` and not the columns only found in 'Vec'

Comment: Not just `union`. I want the resultant matrix will contain all columns as in `Vec`. If a particular element in `Vec` is not available in the `colnames` of `Mat`, then `NA` will follow

Comment: @BrianSmith can you test now